# man set is not found in bash?

Tags: bash, man, set

I am using bash

I wanted to read the documentation of `set`

But when i typed `man set`,it is showing

```
No manual entry for set
```

But when i code

```
set hit="COVID19"
echo $1
```

it prints as

```
hit=COVID19
```

How to find and add the `man` page of `set` inside the current man pages.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `--help` flag

```
set --help
```

This is a nice link as well: [Linux set and unset commands](https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uset.htm)

Comment: If I do that in Linux Mint, I get `bash: set: --: invalid option`

Comment: @AdminBee, `set --help` would only work in ksh93 and recent versions of `bash` (4.4+). With older `bash`, `help set` would work better. See also `info bash set` (or `info zsh set` for `zsh`'s `set` builtin), and `set --man` (or `set --nroff 2>&1 | man -l -`) in `ksh93`.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thank you, that's good to know (seriously). Still, it was originally meant as a caveat to this answer, and it may be worth including that information in the post.

Comment: You are observing a typical Linux problem. `man set` works on a typical `UNIX` system. That man page however does not include information on the `bash` builtin command but just for the default shells.